# Event listener doesn't get destroyed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, listener

In my angularjs app, I have a directive with the following code:

```js
listener = $rootScope.$on('currentDate', function(e, now) {
  console.log('date updated.')
}, true);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  console.log('event destroyed.')
  listener();
});
```

It's a listener that waits for a broadcast from the rootscope that passes the current date every second. As I don't want this listener to linger after the directive is destroyed, I call the listener return function (which is supposed to unbind the listener) in the destroy event.

I can see in the log that destroy is called, but the listener still gets called every second.

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Is using the rootScope for that "angular-friendly"?

Comment: Seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/6t2myzf3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not destroying it on the rootScope though:

```
listener = $rootScope.$on('currentDate', function(e, now) {
  console.log('date updated.')
}, true);

$rootScope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  console.log('event destroyed.')
  listener();
});
```

So after seeing your comment, thinking about it, this might be better:

```
link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
  const listener = scope.$on('currentDate', function(e, now) {
    console.log('date updated.')
  }, true);

  scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
    listener();
  });
}
```

Another question though is, if you are in a directive then perhaps you shouldn't use $rootScope, but use 'scope' (using the example above).

Comment: it didn't... the issue with that is that I'm just reloading the data that renders that directive, so the rootScope never gets destroyed and so this event doesn't even get called. :/

Comment: So, you're doing this from the directive's link() function?

Comment: Updated answer to include change if you're in a directive that might help you.

Comment: hmm to be honest I don't really understand this new solution. do you care to explain? (I just included it in my code and no difference, btw)

Comment: Updated it again, thinking about you being in a directive but using $rootScope, which I don't think you need to do.

Comment: oh, now it makes more sense (and works!)... I really don't know why I was binding it to rootscope. beginner's nonsense hehe. thank you!